# GLUT: blank window

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, freeglut

I successfully compiled this code using latest freeglut but I'm constantly getting a blank window filled with the color specified in *glClearColor* function. This simple program is from a Interactive Computer Graphics textbook provided by my college. I copied it word for word and it still doesn't work. It should render 2 squares rotating.

I use gcc on windows 7 machine:

$    gcc -Iinlude -Llib -o sample.exe sample.cpp -lfreeglut -lopengl32

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void rashape(int width, int height);
void display();
void renderScene();
void animate(int value);
void drawSquare();
int angle = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Primjer animacije");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutTimerFunc(20, animate, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
}

void animate(int value) {
    angle++;
    if(angle >= 360) kut = 0;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(20, animate, 0);
}

void display() {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    renderScene();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int width, int height) {
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width-1, 0, height-1, 0, 1);
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void drawSquare() {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(  0.0f,   0.0f);
    glVertex2f(100.0f,   0.0f);
    glVertex2f(100.0f, 100.0f);
    glVertex2f(  0.0f, 100.0f);
    glEnd();
}

void renderScene() {
    glPointSize(6);
    glColor3f(0.3f, 1.0f, 0.3f);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef( 150.0f, 160.0f, 0.0f);
    glScalef(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.0f);
    glRotatef((float)kut, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(-50.0f, -50.0f, 0.0f);
    drawSquare();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef( 400.0f, 160.0f, 0.0f);
    glScalef(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.0f);
    glRotatef(-(float)kut, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(-50.0f, -50.0f, 0.0f);
    drawSquare();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never call `reshape()`. Thus, the default projection  matrix is used, which puts `(0,0)` at the center of the screen and has a view 'radius' of 1. As a result, your squares are being rendered far off screen.

Calling `reshape()` with appropriate parameters before trying to render anything should work. What you would really want to do, though, is set it as a `glutReshapeFunc()` so that the projection matrix adjusts automatically to resizing. This is easy to do:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // ... stuff ...
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    // ... more stuff ...
}
```

The viewport should now automatically adjust to window resizing.

Comment: Actually the really sane solution would be to set the projection matrix in the display function, where this actually belongs. (It's a drawing state manipulation)

Answer (score 0):

A classic pitfall is backface culling. Not sure if it applies to your case but try calling

```
glDisable( GL_CULL_FACE );
```

before drawing and see if makes a difference.